# unrelated struts actions calls with struts2.X

Tags: java, ajax, json, struts2

Working on one of the big web application with struts 2.x ( currently using struts-core 2.3.4.1 )

In this app when I call an action through ajax , after returning from an action, an unrelated some other action getting called. I didn't find the solution even after spending many days.

Later I thought to create simple sample app , which has just two actions, no web service calls, just one jsp, and only one action mapped ( I tried mapping other action too in struts.xml) again the same problem

Please find the code below

Struts Action Class

```
 package lpaction;

public class PlanAction {

    public String updatePlan() {
        return "PLAN_ACTION_SUCCESS";
    }

    public String getPlans() {
        return "PLAN1_ACTION_SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

JSP Code

```
    <%@page import="org.json.JSONArray"%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java"
    import="java.sql.*" errorPage=""%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Client</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/Libs/utility.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/Libs/jquery1.10.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/Libs/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/Libs/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function callme(){
            var formdata = "";
            console.log("formData =  "+formdata);
            $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',      
                      url: 'plan',
                      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                      async: false,
                      data :formdata, 
                      cache: false,
                      processData:false,
                      datatype: "json",
                      success: function(response) {
                          alert("Success"+response);
                      },
                      error: function(e) { 
                          alert("Fail");
                      }
                });

        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <input type="button" onclick="callme()"> press me </>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Struts.xml file

```
     <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="lessonPlan" extends="json-default">
        <action name="plan" class="lpaction.PlanAction"
            method="updatePlan">
            <result name="PLAN_ACTION_SUCCESS" type="json" />
            <result name="PLAN_ACTION_FAIL" type="json" />
        </action>

        <!-- <action name="plan1" class="lpaction.PlanAction"
            method="getPlans">
            <result name="PLAN1_ACTION_SUCCESS" type="json" />
            <result name="PLAN1_ACTION_FAIL" type="json" />
        </action> -->

    </package>
</struts>
```

Web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>testClient</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>testClient</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

If I put breakpoint in both action methods, the first action method will be called after that second action method will call.

Why second action method is getting called ?
Infact second action is not at all mapped ( Note I tried to uncomment that action mapping in struts.xml, still same problem )

I am using the following JAR files
[image]

Comment: Is that a bug in struts ?
http://wnct.cn/ajax/webSiteJsonAction!webCount

Comment: (Probably) unrelated, but you *must* not deploy your own Servlet implementation as part of your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason your `getPlans` method is called when you call `plan` action is that the method name starts with **`get`**. Since you have not specified any **Customized Serialization and Deserialization** for your JSON Result everything that starts with **`get`** will be Serialized, that means at the time of generating response `getPlans` method will be called because of Serialization.

You can change the action method name to overcome this issue, also refer this **[JSON Plugin Documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/json-plugin.html)** for controlling your json object sent in response. If you don't control json object in response it can lead to unintentional data exposure which intern cause security risks and .

**Update:** As per documents

> The serialization process is recursive, meaning that the whole object
>   graph, starting on the action class (base class not included) will be
>   serialized (root object can be customized using the "root" attribute)

This means every thing in action will be serialized(so that means ***every method*** with prefix **`get`** will be called), And this is done with recursion that is going in depth of object excluding base class.

Comment: that worked ... Isn't it a bug in struts json plugin ? It should call method only if there is a member variable declared in action class with a getter method . other wise it should not call .

Comment: In the link given by Yogi, which is JSON Plugin documentation its given as,
**The JSON plugin provides a "json" result type that serializes actions into JSON** 
hence your action got serialized to serialize it called get+actionName  ie getPlans.